# Is there a better approach for achieving this code snippet?

Tags: python, pytest

I am developing a design to automate some testcases using pytest framework. I am using YAML file format to pass input parameters for each testcase. Each testcase may call one or more library level methods. And each library method can call more than one library method in turn. Here I need to pass many number of arguments required for the internal library calls. Is there any better approach to the following design?

input.yaml file takes input parameters for each testcase. Testcase calls the library API and this API may call many other APIs to recover from different error conditions. Currently I am thinking of passing all the required parameters from input.yaml.

**input.yaml**

```
testcases:
     testcase1:
         param1: value1
         param2: value2
         paramN: valueN
```

**testsuite.py**

```
def test_testcase1(self, **kwargs):
    libApi(force=True, **kwargs)
```

**lib.py**

```
def libApi(force=False, **kwargs):
   if force:
      try:
          api(**kwargs)
      except CustomException1:
          api1(**kwargs)
          api4(**kwargs)
      except CustomException2:
          api2(**kwargs)
          api3(**kwargs)
      except CustomExceptionN:
          apiN(**kwargs)
   else:
       api(**kwargs)
```

In the above code snippet, when `force=True`, many `api()` may be called and I need to pass all the parameters required for all of these apis from input.yaml as I do not know which error condition occurs. Is there a better approach to this design?

Comment: "as I do not know which error condition" I think the custom exceptions raised give sufficient context as to what error occurred. If the situation here is that you're not enforcing the respective signature of the functions, you can take of that by delineating them in wrapper functions.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule, Before I run my testsuite, I am not sure what are all the CustomExceptions the control flow will go through and what apis will be called. So, I must need to pass all the params required for all the apis used in libApi.